# angularJS basics struggling - controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

im new to AngularJS and im having trouble creating a controller  for my page

1. its a simple page that load app.js file that has  $scope.name = "james";
   and i use the expression {{ $scope.name }} to display that value which isnt coming up.. but when i run {{ 2 + 4 }} it shows 6 so angular is working..
2. another thing is when i open the page in safari the expressions are being displayed  raw (meaning : '{{ 2 + 4 }}') but chrome would run it  and will show the results..

here is my code..
thanks for helping

```
HTML
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="app.js"></script>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
        {{  $scope.name }}
        {{  2 + 4 }}


        </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

app.js

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

   $scope.name = "James"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

seems to be working ok for me here is a plunkr.  https://plnkr.co/edit/uXqvoIrgNjEZq8cHRE3Z?p=preview

I am using the angular style guide.   https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
       {{  vm.name }}
        {{  2 + 4 }}
    </div> 
</div>
```

---

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

   function myCtrl(){
       /* jshint validthis: true */
       var vm=this;
       vm.name = "James";
   } 

})();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as it's recommended to use controllerAs w/ AngularJS controllers.

Answer (score 1):

your issue here is that you are misunderstanding how `$scope` works.

`$scope` is a special object provided by AngularJs which allows you to add properties to it, which AngularJs will attach Watchers to, for Two Way Binding.  In your HTML expressions (`{{ }}`), you don't refer to the `$scope`, you refer to the property of `$scope` that you are interested in.

In other words, instead of `{{  $scope.name }}`, you should use simply `{{ name }}`.

Note that there are many style guides which will suggest alternatives to using `$scope`, but the most important aspect of `$scope` in more advanced situations is to *always use a dot in your bindings, if possible*.